# Node size in graph with pgf 3.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to draw some graphs with [`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) 3.0, but the size of the nodes are not being taken into account when laying out the graph using spring layouts.

Here is an example document:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}

\newcommand\text[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|}%
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}\\\hline
    X $\to$ A B C\\\hline
    X $\to$ x y\\
    Y $\to$ ( L )\\
    S $\to \bullet$ x X\\\hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph [spring electrical Walshaw 2000 layout] {
  a/[as=\text{first}]
  -> ["S"]
  b/[as=\text{second}];

  a
  -> ["k"]
  c/[as=\text{third}]
  -> ["x"]
  d/[as=fourth]
  -> ["y"]
  e/[as=fifth];
};

\end{document}
```

The output follows:

[image: output pdf document]

How to fix this issue?

It seems to work for some other layouts, like the simple necklace.

Comment: I don't know much about the graph libraries, but I think you could always manualy spread things out with `shift={(<x shift value>,<y shift value>)}`.

Comment: Add `node distance=3cm` to graph options

Comment: In order to test @PeterGrill suggestion, I added the option `nodes={shift={(3cm,3cm)}}` to the `graph` command, but nothing changed in the output. Do the force-based algorithms for graph drawing ignore this option?

Comment: Adding an option for the node distance as suggested by @percusse works, but it seems to have the drawback of producing the same node distance for all edges. What would be really nice is the possibility of specifying the node distance measured from node borders and not from node centers. Can it be done?